# which hypothesis testing model to use for binary data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, dataset, binary-data

I have a dataset that contains 20000 chess matches. I hypothesize that 'is white more advantageous?', and there are features like standard match time of each match and the number of turns in each match. However, since this is binary data, I don't know which test to use. Although I searched for two hours, I couldn't find useful information. Thus, here is my question: 'which hypothesis testing model to use for binary data.'

Comment: How is this binary when each match has three possible results?

Comment: That's true but what I'm comparing is not these three possible outcomes, but rather only white and black winning,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a one-sided, one-sample test of proportions. If $p$ represents the proportion of games where White wins, then your null hypothesis is that $p = 0.5$ (i.e. White has no better chance of winning than random chance, which is 50/50) and the alternative hypothesis would be that $p \geq 0.5$ (i.e. White has a greater than random chance of winning).