# logistic regression and linear regression have the same output

Tags: regression, logistic, dataset, linear

I have a dataset that contains 20000 chess matches. Using two variables from this dataset, I created one logistic regression and one linear regression. the first variable was whitewon: has 1 for every match white won and zero for every match black won. The second one was turns: the number of moves played in the match. The two models I created from these variables have the same output. How is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "have the same output"?

Comment: They both showed the same graph. They both predicted the line.

Comment: What "line"? What is plotted against what?

Comment: default of `family="Gaussian"` in both cases?

Comment: x-axis showed the turns and y-axis had only two values:1 and 0. 1 meant white won, 0 meant black won. the predicted line showed the possibility of white winning regarding the turns variable.

Comment: PS: in logistic regression, I used predict_proba in python.

Comment: You should link to your related Q: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/506243/which-hypothesis-testing-model-to-use-for-binary-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics of your problem, it may simply be that OLS models the conditional average of the dependent variable, while logistic regression models the probability of being 1. Especially with a large number of data points, the two may simply coincide.

For instance, you may have 1000 matches with 40 moves, 550 won by White and 450 by black. (No draws?) Then logistic regression will model a *probability* of 0.55, whereas OLS will model a *mean* of 0.55. Same number, *slightly* different interpretation.